# Can't Find Elements on Silverlight App with LeanFT

Tags: silverlight, leanft

I was trying to use LeanFT for testing Silverlight App for our project and I faced with one big problem, which is- The Spy Agent can not find elements on that particular App. I was trying to change Engine from LeanFT Setting, still the same. The interesting thing that Object Spy Indent. works well using HP UFT. I know that one of the solution will be to migrate all the Object Repositories to LeanFT, but I think is not the best solution.
Have you faced with the same problem with LeanFT?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge LeanFT supports WPF, Winforms, etc. but currently doesn't support Silverlight.

So spy will recognize your app as STD objects (standard window).

For the same reason, if you want to automatically interact with this app using LeanFT code, you'll currently have to use (example for C#) the [STD SDK](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/HelpCenter/Content/CodeSamples_.NET/CodeEx.NETSTD.htm) or use the [`Mouse`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/NetSDKReference/webframe.html#HP.LFT.SDK~HP.LFT.SDK.Mouse.html) class to generate events *on coordinates*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Some part will work as you mentioned.